# Why is the function implemented with hardware generally considered to be more secure than that implemented with software?

Tags: security, hardware

everyone.

When we talk about information security, we usually think that the more the system rely on secure hardware, the saver the system is than that rely secured software for the same security function. Why? Won't a secure hardware have a bug within it?

Thanks

Comment: That entirely depends on the type of security you're using, but generally speaking - a good HW security solution is further up in the chain of trust, so there may be less vectors of attack compared to a good SW security solution.

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon your system. What type of system are you talking about.

Stand alone system, server, application system etc. Suppose if you talk about server, developing firewall using s/w is not enough. We have to use different h/w devices as well as securing the server from different hazards.

When we talk about the stand alone application there can be firewall, password security and also user lock devices. So every system has its own type of security requirements.